# Are there any event listeners for windows taskbar property change in Action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I wants to know are there any event listeners for windows **taskbar** property change in Actionscript-3 because i wants to adjust my application canvas window size according to taskbar height i.e if i will change the windows taskbar height, accordingly my application canvas size will change.

Does anyone have an idea what are the event listeners or any other possible ways to solve this problem ?

Comment: Describe your usecase more clearly. Is this for Adobe AIR? Why not just maximize the application through `NativeWindow.maximize()`? If you don't want to maximize your application, how is the taskbar size relevant to your application?

Comment: Hi @DodgerThud ,I wants to change my Adobe AIR application canvas size according to taskbar height i.e if i will increase the height of the taskbar then application canvas height automatically decrease and if i will again decrease taskbar height then my application canvas height will automatically increase.

Comment: There is no such functionality built-in, but you could use [Screen.visibleBounds](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html#visibleBounds) to determine the space of the work area of your screen. If the resolution is 1920x1080, and you get a visible bounds with a height of 1000, the taskbarsize is 80.

Comment: Alternatively, write a Native Extension that will dispatch an Event for this, by determing if the work area has changed through C/C++.